# Why does this SQL work? DATE keyword + date string (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: sql, date, syntax, google-bigquery

While examining a former colleague's code, I came across the following: `DATE'2019-01-01'`

Why does this work? It is used in a BigQuery Standard SQL context.

Wouldn't it need to be `DATE('2019-01-01')` ? As per the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date

Comment: Your link uses the same syntax

Comment: It does not. The link provides three possible uses of the function:
1. DATE(year, month, day)
2. DATE(timestamp_expression[, timezone])
3. DATE(datetime_expression)
None of which ignores the parentheses

Comment: quote: "SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE '2010-07-07', DATE '2008-12-25', DAY) AS days_diff;".

Comment: Well, I guess you are technically correct, but that piece you quote is not under the part dedicated to the DATE function, but to the DATE_DIFF function, so the documentation is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why both syntax are allowed, but they produce the same data type. So it won't matter if you use either since you won't be encountering data type mismatch. I tested it using [bqutil.fn.typeof](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#typeofinput-any-type) to test the data type for both syntax. See testing below:

Query:

```
SELECT DATE('2019-01-01') as date_1,
       DATE'2019-01-01' as date_2,
       bqutil.fn.typeof(DATE('2019-01-01')) as typeof_date1,
       bqutil.fn.typeof(DATE'2019-01-01') as typeof_date2
```

Both syntax produce `DATE` data type.

Output:

[image]